# JMeter, what is meant the resulting graphics?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing, throughput

I have the following settings:

```
Number of Threads(users): 10
Rump-up period(in second): 0
Target throughput (in samples per minute): 40.0
```

And I can not understand what is meant the resulting graphics 
[image]

Ten points in each sample, on the graph Throughput, represent ten Threads(users)?
Why is the distance between points in each subsequent sample becomes smaller?
Why when Rump-up period=0, graph of the Throughput intermittent and decreasing?

When Rump-up period>1, graph of the Throughput smooth and increasing:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so throughput is stated at the bottom, average about 400/min @ 10 users, so 40/user. the green dots show this. first graph shows that throughput had a steep climb, dropped off after first 10 requests, then climbed again, etc. until it leveled out to the average. no scale is shown for this on the graph, but the average is stated.

average is showing that when the server is initially sent 10 requests, it takes longer to 'spin up' and settle in than when the first 10 requests are sent gradually. cause is entirely dependent on environment and architecture.

showing the data on the graph (check the data box) will give more indication of what is actually happening and help to explain the average and throughput lines.

feel free to post the graph with data showing and ask more questions :)